# declare variable in flex vs flash?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, variables, declare

This code gives an error Description
1026: Constructor functions must be instance methods.   joe.mxml    /joe/src    line 7  Flex Problem

Why. This is how I declare public variables in flash. Why doesn't it work in Flex? 
I also tried var joe:String="winning"; still doesn't work.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        var joe="winning";
        function changelabel()
        {
            myButton.label=joe; 
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button x="50" y="42" label="Button" id="myButton" click="changelabel()"/>
```

Comment: Is there some resource for things you cannot do in flex but can do in flash.

Comment: Technically speaking Flex is a framework built on ActionScript 3, so anything you can do in AS3 in the Flash Authoring Tool you can also do in Flex. Flex in fact gives you more options, not less. The biggest difference between Flex Builder (the software you're probably using to create your flex application) and the Flash Authoring Tool is the way graphical elements are linked into your code. In the Flash Authoring Tool you can export graphics from your library, plus you have a mini-photoshop style toolbox to work with. In Flex Builder you have to manually "[Embed]" images into classes.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're running into this issue because your variable name (joe) is the same as your MXML file's name. Therefore when it sees something called "joe" in the code, it assumes that that's the constructor - and it's getting confused because the constructor is a string instead of an instance method.

Does that make sense?

Just change the name of your string variable from "joe" to "myString".

Also, pay attention to the warnings Flash Builder is giving you - it may seem trivial, but you really should specify access modifiers for all methods and properties (ie instead of "var myString" make it "public var myString".

Also, you will want to specify data types for both variables and functions.

protected var myString:String
protected function changeLabel():void

These measures, taken now, will help you to write better code that's easier to manage moving forward.

Good luck!

Comment: I found evidence and posted sources and indicate this issue can also be linked to another error. But you're right, this is most likely the right answer. I accept your downvote, as I myself have downvoted people for posting answers that are erroneous. Thanks for posting a comment with the explanation for the downvote.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! If you get a chance, make sure you accept my answer - it helps both of us to earn reputation points, plus it makes it clear to future people visiting the site that this solved the problem. S/O is all about building a useful archive of Q&A! :)

Comment: +1 as I suspect this is the right answer. However; I strongly doubt that the Flash Player would give a warning about specifying access modifiers for methods/properties.  I think you meant to refer to the Flex Compiler; and even then it wouldn't be an error it would be a warning.

Comment: Good catch, sorry - I mean Flash Builder, not Flash Player. I copied/pasted this code into a new Flex project in FB4 and got warnings for that stuff so I passed them along is all. I'll edit to make sure it says Flash Builder, not Flash Player. Good catch!